# Cannot load modal popup in cakephp 3

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cakephp-3.0

I want to load modal pop up on click of an edit link. But it takes to new page. I have used e.preventDefault() function but it is not working. Below is my code.
It is taking me to http://localhost/projectname/PanelAdmin/Products/edit/1. Please help to solve my issue i am new to cakephp.

> View.ctp

```
<li>
          <?php              
          echo $this->Html->link("Edit Profucts","/PanelAdmin/Products/edit/".$prod->product_id, array('update' => '#flexModal','htmlAttributes' => array('data-toggle' => 'modal','data-target' => '#flexModal')));
              ?>
    </li> 

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a[data-target=#flexModal]").click(function(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        $("#flexModal .modal-body").load(target, function() {
            $("#flexModal").modal("show");
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

> View: edit.ctp

```
<div class="modal" data-target="#flexModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h3 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

> ProductsController.php

```
public function edit()
{
    $this->render('edit', 'ajax');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should wrap your attribute value with `'` while selecting your link element it should be `$("a[data-target='#flexModal']")` instead of this `$("a[data-target=#flexModal]")`.

So the final js code looks like this now

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("a[data-target='#flexModal']").click(function(ev) {
       ev.preventDefault();
       $("#flexModal .modal-body").load(target, function() {
          $("#flexModal").modal("show");
       });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Anand for your answer. This solution is working only if my modal is on same view. But i have different view for my modal there it is not working.I want that view to call from controller.

Comment: try including that modal view to your main view i.e. `edit.ctp` to `view.ctp`, this link might help you to do that https://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Developing-with-CakePHP/Views.html